# What is the relationship between the arrow operators (->) in C and Java?

Tags: java, c, lambda

I understand that in C, the following:

```
(*my_struct).member
```

is equivalent to:

```
my_struct -> member
```

But I'm just beginning to learn lambda expressions in Java, and I thought that figuring out how they're similar to the use of the arrow in C might be useful. Are they at all related?

Answer (score 2):

No. They are not at all related. C and Java are different languages, with very different syntax.